# Why my "call" doesn't waste all the gas?

Tags: solidity, gas

While doing an [openzepplin challange](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/20) (***please do not provide me an answer***), I tried to create a new contract `Con1` that waste **most** of the gas (but not all) when calling `Con1.withdraw`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Denial {

    address public partner; // withdrawal partner - pay the gas, split the withdraw
    address public constant owner = address(0xA9E);
    uint timeLastWithdrawn;
    mapping(address => uint) withdrawPartnerBalances; // keep track of partners balances

    function setWithdrawPartner(address _partner) public {
        partner = _partner;
    }

    // withdraw 1% to recipient and 1% to owner
    function withdraw() public {
        uint amountToSend = address(this).balance / 100;
        // perform a call without checking return
        // The recipient can revert, the owner will still get their share
        console.log("stav0",gasleft());
        (bool s,) = partner.call{value:amountToSend}("");
        require(s,"failed to call!!!");
        console.log("stav5",gasleft());
        payable(owner).transfer(amountToSend);
        // keep track of last withdrawal time
        timeLastWithdrawn = block.timestamp;
        withdrawPartnerBalances[partner] +=  amountToSend;
    }

    // allow deposit of funds
    receive() external payable {}

    // convenience function
    function contractBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

contract Con1 {
     Denial public d = new Denial();
    //  Denial public d = Denial(payable(0x6A358FD7B7700887b0cd974202CdF93208F793E2));

    function addMySelf() public {
        // payable(0x6A358FD7B7700887b0cd974202CdF93208F793E2).transfer(0);
        // Denial d = Denial(payable(0x6A358FD7B7700887b0cd974202CdF93208F793E2));
        d.setWithdrawPartner(address(this));
    }

    function widthraw()public {
        addMySelf();
        d.withdraw();
    }

    receive() external payable {
        console.log("stav1",gasleft());
        uint256 i = 0;
        while (gasleft() >= 4000){
            i++;
            d.contractBalance();
        }
        console.log("stav4",gasleft());
    }
}
```

#### Expected gas-left logs:

```
stav0 1801598
stav1 1769491
stav4 3622
stav5 <less than 3622 gas>
```

#### Actual gas-left logs:

```
stav0 1801598
stav1 1769491
stav4 3622
stav5 30626     <<<<----------- How can it be?!
```

#### Question

Why `stav5 30626` is printed? How can it be?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

If the developer does not specify custom gas amount when calling an external contract, not all the gas can be used in the external call, only 63/64 of the current `gasleft()`.

Example:

By calling `B.b1()` with `1M` gas:

```
contract A{
   function receive() public {
      // `gasleft()` == 1M * 63/64
      
   }
}

contract B{
   A a = 0x....address of A...

   function b1() public {
       // `gasleft()` == 1M
       address(a).call{value:1000}("");
       // `gasleft()` == 1M * 1/64 + any gas left from `a.receive()`
   }
}
```

---

Source:

https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/

Level: `Denial`

> Note: An external CALL can use at most 63/64 of the gas currently available at the time of the CALL. Thus, depending on how much gas is required to complete a transaction, a transaction of sufficiently high gas (i.e. one such that 1/64 of the gas is capable of completing the remaining opcodes in the parent call) can be used to mitigate this particular attack.